# Integral solution property in PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I encounter the following problem in Evan's PDE:

[image]

I feel I should use the property: [image]

but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Harry49 is right, and you can use the method in that link. Another easier proof is roughly speaking to use the test function $v(x,t)=1_{\{ t< t_0\}}$ in the weak formulation (i) and the property falls right out. Of course you need to approximate $v$ by smooth functions to make it rigorous.